# can't get respons as String

Tags: java, android, web-services

I tried to do a request to a rest Webservice server.
My request is in JSON format and my response is a string.
When I try to do the request I get:

> I/ERROR: com.androidnetworking.error.ANError: org.json.JSONException:
> Value עסקה of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

This is my code:

```
JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
try {//json format

    res.put("ErrorCode","000");
    Log.i("req",res.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
AndroidNetworking.post("https://gateway20.pelecard.biz/services/GetErrorMessageHe")//send the json object to the method
        .addJSONObjectBody(res)
        .setTag("test")
        .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
        .build()
        .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                returnMyString(response.toString());

            }
            @Override
            public void onError(ANError error) {
                Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
            }
            private void returnMyString(String myString) {
                Log.i("res",myString);
            }
        });
```

How can I get a String response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a string, but you used getAsString which is wrong

```
  AndroidNetworking.post("https://gateway20.pelecard.biz/services/GetErrorMessageHe")//send the json object to the method
            .addJSONObjectBody(res)
            .setTag("test")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsString(new StringRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: "+response );
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onError: "+anError.getMessage() );
                }
                private void returnMyString(String myString) {
                    Log.e("res",myString);
                }
            });
```